# Dynamically loaded CSS having no effect in a Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, css, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have dynamically loaded a CSS file, and placed it inside a `style` tag in a Windows 8 app.

Here's how I load the CSS

```
function loadHeaders() {
    var monobookCSSURL = "http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/MediaWiki:Monobook.css?action=raw&ctype=text/css";

    WinJS.xhr({ url: monobookCSSURL }).then(loadCSS, xhrError);
}

function loadCSS(result) {
    var css = result.responseText;

    var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerText = css;

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
}
```

When I use the DOM Explorer in Visual Studio to look at what is loaded, I see exactly what I expect, the final tag in the `head` being a `style` containing my CSS.

However, when I view my page, non of the CSS that is loaded comes into affect.

I tested this by adding another `style` tag manually into the HTML source, and that had effect, but the dynamic one didn't.

How can I make this CSS have an effect?

Here is the style tag generated:

```
 #p-cactions ul li {
}
#p-cactions ul li a {
}
 #content {
}
 body {
    background: rgb(244, 248, 255);
}
 div.tleft {
    border: currentColor;
}
 div.tright {
    margin-left: 13px;
}
 .content-bg {
    background: white;
}
pre {
    overflow: auto;
}
.pBody {
    background-color: rgb(222, 227, 232);
}
body {
     background: #103A5A url(http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/lego/images/f/f0/Studs-tile.png);
}
#p-personal li a {
     color: #DEE3E8;
}
.portlet h5 {
     color: #FFFFFF;  display: block;  height: 15px;  background-color: #355C70;  text-transform: Capitalize;
}
body[class*='ns-118'] {
}
body[class*='ns-119'] {
}
body[class*='ns-118'] #p-personal li a {
     color: #DEE8E3;
}
body[class*='ns-119'] #p-personal li a {
     color: #DEE8E3;
}
body[class*='ns-118'].portlet h5 {
     color: #FFFFFF;  display: block;  height: 15px;  background-color: #35705C;  text-transform: Capitalize;
}
body[class*='ns-119'].portlet h5 {
     color: #FFFFFF;  display: block;  height: 15px;  background-color: #35705C;  text-transform: Capitalize;
}
body[class*='ns-116'] {
}
body[class*='ns-117'] {
}
body[class*='ns-116'] #p-personal li a {
     color: #E8DEE3;
}
body[class*='ns-117'] #p-personal li a {
     color: #E8DEE3;
}
body[class*='ns-116'].portlet h5 {
     color: #FFFFFF;  display: block;  height: 15px;  background-color: #90152C;  text-transform: Capitalize;
}
body[class*='ns-117'].portlet h5 {
     color: #FFFFFF;  display: block;  height: 15px;  background-color: #90152C;  text-transform: Capitalize;
}
body[class*='Forum_Brickiforums'] {
}
body[class*='Forum_Brickiforums'] #p-personal li a {
     color: #E8DEE3;
}
body[class*='Forum_Brickiforums'].portlet h5 {
     color: #FFFFFF;  display: block;  height: 15px;  background-color: #B0B02C;  text-transform: Capitalize;
}
#title-rating2 {
     display: none;
}
#footer {
     background: #DEE3E8;  border-color: #355C70;
}
.wikiaOnly {
     display: none;
}
div.User-help-badge-1 {
    left: 500px; top: 2px; position: absolute;
}
div.User-help-badge-2 {
    left: 540px; top: 2px; position: absolute;
}
div.User-help-badge-3 {
    left: 580px; top: 2px; position: absolute;
}
div.User-help-badge-4 {
    left: 620px; top: 2px; position: absolute;
}
div.User-help-badge-5 {
    left: 660px; top: 2px; position: absolute;
}
.infoboxtoc .toc {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: currentColor; width: 100%;
}
.infoboxtoc #toctitle {
    display: none;
}
.infoboxtoc .NavHead {
    padding-right: 2px; padding-bottom: 12px; float: right;
}
.infoboxtoc .NavFrame {
    margin-bottom: -23px;
}
.ttbutton {
    border-radius: 2px; left: 114px; top: 200px; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px; display: none; position: fixed; transform: rotate(90deg); background-color: rgb(173, 173, 173); -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.wikia-menu-button {
    display: none !important;
}
:first-of-type.portlet > .pBody > ul > li:not([id]) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you show us the generated style tag.

Comment: Ahh apologies, at first glance it sounded like you were simply trying to include an external css into the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the head tag, do it through the DOM api. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh996817.aspx) page should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got a `JavaScript runtime error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.` error when trying this though!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682536/trouble-programatically-adding-css-to-ie) post any help?

Comment: Yup, using `d.createStyleSheet().cssText = ...` solved the problem. Thanks!